# How to make listview to update the view when the images download is done

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am not a pro of android developing. Please forgive me for asking such a noob question.

So far, I used `BaseAdapter` and `ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` to handle the row text view.

My question is what happens if I want to use two ArrayList such as `ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` and `ArrayList<Bitmap>` to handle row text and image?

Can I still using `notifydatasetchanged` to update my ListView like what I did so far.

I want to ask the listView to update the list after the images is finished downloaded by using `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: you want to add new item to list view or you wish to download images separatly from item body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases which you might  want check this good [tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 1):

Make your own custom class that includes both Map and Bitmap.. And define the arrayList of this class.. something like this:

```
class MyCustomClass{
  private Map<String, String> myMap;
  private Bitmap myBitmap;

   public MyCustomClass(Map<String,String> map, Bitmap bitmap)
   {
     this.myMap = map;
     this.myBitmap = bitmap;
    }
 }
```

And in your activity:

```
ArrayList<MyCustomClass> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
```